# Python, how can I print an odd and even digits from entered number

Tags: python, for-loop

For example, if the number 34560 is entered, then it has 3 even numbers (4, 6 and 0) and 2 odd numbers (3 and 5).

````
for num in int(len(number)):
    if num % 2 != 0:
        print(num, end=" ")```
````

Comment: Please show your attempt

Comment: number = int(input("Enter number: "))
for num in int(len(number)):
    if num % 2 != 0:
        print(num, end=" ")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use for example like this:

```
number = 34560

even = [int(x) for x in str(number) if int(x)%2 == 0]
odd = [int(x) for x in str(number) if int(x)%2 != 0]
print(even)
print(odd)
```

Comment: list(even.append(int(i)) if int(i)%2==0 else odd.append(int(i)) for i in str(number))